# What could be making this vibrating sound?

Tags: vibration, noise, mazda-3

I have a 2007 Mazda 3 4 door sedan 2.0 liter. The problem is when I press the accelerator, I hear a lot of vibration on the passenger side.  Please help... I've looked at a lot of questions and answers on here but that does not sound like a broken motor mount. You can only hear it inside the car.

I've tried listening outside while the throttle was being pushed, but didn't hear anything. What could it be?

Comment: Could it be a bad CV axle shaft that needs replacing?

Comment: Shoot a video of what you're hearing and point the camera in the rough direction and upload it to youtube and link your question to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing could be any number of things. It sounds like something may be vibrating against the body or frame, which transfers audible sound to the interior of the car. It could be anything...bad motor mount, loose exhaust pipe, rough running engine, transmission mount, etc.

You will need safely jack the car up, or put it on a lift, to inspect the components under the car. It could be as simple as a heat shield touching an exhaust pipe after being bent from road debris.

Don't rule out motor mounts by sound alone. A weak motor mount can allow the engine, when revved, to twist enough that something touches causing vibrations.

Comment: My money's on motor mount.  Have a helper rev the engine a bit in neutral while you watch the engine.